# Selectize.js: How to preload already selected tags from the database into the input field (Meteor & MongoDB/JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor, selectize.js

In admins can tag **new** "News and Events" entries. This works fine and the document in the `NewsEvents` looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "nbMJdwjkDjZ4twkvi",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "math", 
        "analysis", 
        "beginner"
    ],
    "title" : "brand new article for analysis beginners",
    "description" : "testing here the tagging system",
    "type" : "news",
    "createdAt" : "Thu, 21 Apr 2016 04:53:21",
    "publishedAt" : "Thu, 21 Apr 2016 04:53:21",
    "modifiedAt" : "Thu, 21 Apr 2016 04:54:15"
}
```

The Tags are saved in a separate collection called `Tags`. An example:

```
{
    "_id" : "P4XoEtsogwhDvNNTv",
    "name" : "math"
}
```

**Problem:** An admin wants to edit/add the tags after a few days. How is it possible to prepopuluate the chosen tags from the database?

This is my helper for the `news-events-edit.js`:

```
Template.adminNewsEventsEdit.onRendered(function() {
  ...
  // Get an array of the existing tags
    var tagOptions = Tags.find().fetch();

    $('#newsKeywords').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button'],
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        valueField: 'name',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: 'name',
        create: true,
        highlight: true,
        maxOptions: 5,
        options: tagOptions,
        onItemAdd: function (item) {
            // Check to see if tag exists in Tags collection
            // by querying the database for the tag name
            // and checking the length of the result
            var existingTag = Tags.find({"name": item}).fetch().length;
            if (!existingTag ) {
                // Add the tag to the Tags collection
                Tags.insert({"name": item});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the api function `addItem` [(see here)](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md)

E.g.

```
Template.adminNewsEventsEdit.onRendered(function() {
    ...

    // Get an array of the existing tags
    var tagOptions = Tags.find().fetch();

    // Set up selectize
    var selectize = $('#newsKeywords').selectize({
       plugins: ['remove_button'],
        ...
    });

    // Get the keywords on this news entry
    var keywords = this.data.keywords;

    // Add each keyword to the selectize.
    _.each(keywords, function(word) {
        // To do this we use the tag _id of each keyword
        var tag = _.find(tagOptions, function(opt){ 
            return opt.name === word; 
        });

        selectize.addItem(tag._id, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought about working with addItem but didn't understand how. Anyhow, your answer didn't prepopulate the input fields with the previously selected tags :( btw: you need a closing bracket for the _.each function.